How to extract all HTML elements style to one file in PhpStorm project or Bitbucket?
I'm building a Symfony project with lots of design.
I was wondering if there is way to extract all CSS styling of every element that has some with
style="..." 

to a unique CSS file while creating a CSS class for these stylings.
Maybe in PhpStorm with the file watcher or something like that or in Bitbucket with pipelines (I'm not used to Bitbucket so that's might make no sense with pipelines).
If anyone already found a way to do that? (I might not be the only one to think about that.)

Check out the webpack encore in symfony documentation.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Hi, I'm already using webpack encore, it doesn't match what i'm asking
